# get position from listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I retrieve data from sqlite database and I display it into listview.
Here the resulting listview:

```
**Name**
Adam
Frank
James
Mike
.......
```

With this code clicking on a name I get his position in listview.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id).
```

Result:

Adam = position 0

Frank = position 1

James = position 2

Mike = position 3

Now, if I retrieve data with WHERE clause

```
(e.g. SELECT * from my table WHERE name like "James")
```

The resulting listview is:

```
**Name**
James
```

and clicking on James I get position 0.

How can I get, instead, position 2?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess it happens because of adapter. It refreshes list with values automatically if you use `CursorLoader`.

Comment: Because it reports the position in the listview (so it's the first item, 0) not the ID in the Database

Comment: Why do you need to do something like this? This is expected behavior if there is a single item in the list. Why not use the database ID for the row instead?

Comment: does this suprise you? how come it does? what were you expecting?

Comment: No, I'm not surprise, Result 0 is correct (first record in listview). I was only wondering if there is a trick to retrieve also the global position.

Comment: The trick is in the `id` argument, the adapter can set that for any elements returned and you get it passed on. Can you show your adapter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get position 0 because you have only one element in your resulting array.You need to take one hash map in which along with name bind its id and get value from name.

Example:HashMap names=new HashMap

When fetch results from database your hashmap will contain key value par like

<"James","2">.

Now extract value 2 by key James.

Comment: also id gives me 0. public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id).     id=intent.getLongExtra("id", 1);     System.out.println(String.valueOf(id));

Comment: This id will not be id of OnItem  Click you have to bind each name with id in your sqlite database like primary key so that in database id of adam is 0,id of frank is 1,id of james is 2 and so on...

Comment: Thank you Joy, I will hashmap it!

Answer (score 2):

you can again reQuery and get the row id which should 2.
or while on click the list item(clickListener) you can move your cursor to that position cursor.moveToPosition(position) then you can also get the long row value by extracting the cursor.

Comment: Filtering query with WHERE clause, change the list and position of every items.